# How to insert view between the items of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I need to show embeded slider (marked green) inside of the list of `recyclerview` items, like on image below:

[image]

I am thinking that I need to change something in my `recyclerview layout manager`, but I have no idea what exactly and guess it is quite complicated. In addition I am using [`FlexboxLayout`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi77qarq6_iAhXLlYsKHeq_BysQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogle%2Fflexbox-layout&usg=AOvVaw2wKHxDNN0kBRTnxAThuzx4) here.

So, could you please help me with the selection of the best approach of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate different view for that position , since you're inflating a different layout there .

This answer will help :- [RecyclerView with multiple view type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6792523)

The basic gist is to use the getItemViewType and return a flag , say 1 for the first red box , 2 for the second and 3 for the third and inflate layout on depending on the viewType param ( in the signature )

Comment: Thanks, I will try that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve it easily to make the layout like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/recycler_view_item_background_color">

    <!-- Red layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/red_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/item_performance_list_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/performance_date_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""/>        

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Blue Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/blue_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/text_item_divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can show or hide the blue layout for every item according to your need.

```
LinearLayout blueLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blue_layout);
blueLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide
blueLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have blue layout or did not asked about it. In addition I am using recycler view and I want to have it only one.